# Yeoman WebApp Modernizr JSHint

Tags: yeoman, modernizr, jshint

Im using the Yeoman Webapp generator with Modernizr (and Bootstrap and Sass/Compass in case that matters).

I have the following in my main.js file:

```
$(function() {
    'use strict';

    Modernizr.addTest('svgasimg', document.implementation.hasFeature('http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image', '1.1'));

    if (!Modernizr.svgasimg) {
        //Do stuff
    }

});
```

Jshint is giving me a "Modernizr not defined" error.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

JSHint is complaining because `Modenrizr` is not builtin to javascript. You just need to add "Modernizr" to the globals list of jshint

either like

`/* global Modernizr */`

at the top of the file, or just listed in the `globals` array in a .jshintrc/Gruntfile